# Run-time error 5 : Invalid procedure call or argument

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2007

I've got the below code and it works completely fine for rows 1 - 46 on it's own populating one table. As soon as I replicate this with a second table to populate it throws Error1.

I've taken out everything below "' Second Table Entry " and works fine ... put back in and same error. On the "Home" sheet it actually populates the tables information but still throws the error which is stopping further vba from executing.

Any ideas? I've been all over google, stackoverflow, superuser and Microsoft MSDN and can't figure out where in the second bit of code is causing it to error.

EDIT: I've checked the debugger and it's highlighting the below code in the second table inserts

```
With Worksheets("Home")
    .Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=.Range("H" & row_ptr), _
    Address:="", _
    SubAddress:=AddStr, _
    TextToDisplay:=Workbooks(ActiveWorkbook.Name).Worksheets("Audit_InFlight").Range("D" & i).Value
End With
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Error1

> Run-time error '5': Invalid procedure call or argument

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
Dim row_ptr As Long
Dim i As Long  
Dim i2 As Long
Dim rownbrMA_Inflight As Long   
Dim rownbrAudit As Long
Dim CurrentWorkbook As Workbook 
Dim InputWorksheet As Worksheet 
Dim DataSourceWorksheet As Worksheet
Dim AuditDataSourceWorksheet As Worksheet

Set CurrentWorkbook = Workbooks(ActiveWorkbook.Name)
Set InputWorksheet = CurrentWorkbook.Sheets("Home")   
Set DataSourceWorksheet = CurrentWorkbook.Sheets("MA_Inflight") 
Set AuditDataSourceWorksheet = CurrentWorkbook.Sheets("Audit_InFlight")

InputWorksheet.Range("A30:M176").Clear  
InputWorksheet.Range("A30:M176").ClearFormats   
InputWorksheet.Range("A30:M176").Interior.Color = RGB(255, 255, 255)
rownbrMA_Inflight = DataSourceWorksheet.Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row   
row_ptr = 31  
For i = 8 To rownbrMA_Inflight 

If DataSourceWorksheet.Range("C" & i).Value = "Open" Then 
InputWorksheet.Rows(row_ptr).Insert Shift:=xlDown 'CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove   
InputWorksheet.Range("A" & row_ptr).Value = DataSourceWorksheet.Range("E" & i).Value  
InputWorksheet.Range("B" & row_ptr).Value = DataSourceWorksheet.Range("F" & i).Value  
AddStr = "MA_Inflight!" & "$F$" & CStr(i)  
ActiveWorkbook.Activate 
Worksheets("Home").Activate  
With Worksheets("Home")   
.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=.Range("B" & row_ptr), _
 Address:="", _
SubAddress:=AddStr, _
TextToDisplay:=Workbooks(ActiveWorkbook.Name).Worksheets("MA_Inflight").Range("F" & i).Value  
End With  
InputWorksheet.Range("C" & row_ptr).Value = DataSourceWorksheet.Range("I" & i).Value   
InputWorksheet.Range("D" & row_ptr).Value = DataSourceWorksheet.Range("J" & i).Value 
InputWorksheet.Range("E" & row_ptr).Value = DataSourceWorksheet.Range("L" & i).Value 
row_ptr = row_ptr + 1   
End If  
Next i  
'============================================================
' Second Table Entry 
'============================================================
rownbrAudit = DataSourceWorksheet.Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row  
row_ptr = Empty  
row_ptr = 31
For i = 8 To rownbrAudit 

If AuditDataSourceWorksheet.Range("B" & i).Value <> "Closed" Then  
InputWorksheet.Rows(row_ptr).Insert Shift:=xlDown, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove  
InputWorksheet.Range("G" & row_ptr).Value = AuditDataSourceWorksheet.Range("B" & i).Value 
InputWorksheet.Range("H" & row_ptr).Value = AuditDataSourceWorksheet.Range("D" & i).Value 
'New code ---------------------------  
AddStr = "Audit_InFlight!" & "$D$" & CStr(i)
ActiveWorkbook.Activate   
Worksheets("Home").Activate   
With Worksheets("Home")  
.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=.Range("H" & row_ptr), _
 Address:="", _
SubAddress:=AddStr, _
TextToDisplay:=Workbooks(ActiveWorkbook.Name).Worksheets("Audit_InFlight").Range("D" & i).Value 
End With   
'-----------------------------------
InputWorksheet.Range("I" & row_ptr).Value = AuditDataSourceWorksheet.Range("G" & i).Value 
InputWorksheet.Range("J" & row_ptr).Value = AuditDataSourceWorksheet.Range("H" & i).Value 
InputWorksheet.Range("K" & row_ptr).Value = AuditDataSourceWorksheet.Range("I" & i).Value 
InputWorksheet.Range("L" & row_ptr).Value = AuditDataSourceWorksheet.Range("J" & i).Value
InputWorksheet.Range("M" & row_ptr).Value = AuditDataSourceWorksheet.Range("K" & i).Value
row_ptr = row_ptr + 1  
End If
Next i

'RemoveBlankCells
'PURPOSE: Deletes single cells that are blank located inside a designated range
Dim rng As Range
'Store blank cells inside a variable
Set rng = InputWorksheet.Range("A30:E50").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks)
'Delete blank cells and shift upward
  rng.Rows.Delete Shift:=xlShiftUp

End Sub
```

Comment: To help pinpoint an answer please state what line the error highlights.

Comment: Hi Zerk, 

I've just checked and the debugger is returning the error on the below 
`code`        
With Worksheets("Home")
            .Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=.Range("H" & row_ptr), _
             Address:="", _
            SubAddress:=AddStr, _
            TextToDisplay:=Workbooks(ActiveWorkbook.Name).Worksheets("Audit_InFlight").Range("D" & i).Value
        End With
`code`

Comment: We can't see line numbers.... Have you tried commenting out sections line by line to determine?

Comment: Have you checked the values of each of the variables involved at this point? I cannot produce this error as is though clearly I don't have your dataset.

Comment: This wont help to resolve your query but might help to improve your code: you don't have to `.Activate` the sheets when you have already created an object that points to the sheet. Also, as you've already created the object.. why not use that? i.e. your line: **`With Worksheets("Home")`** should be replaced by: **`With InputWorksheet`** because you already have the sheet object pointing to that sheet. If you want to learn more about this, search for topics like: **qualifying worksheets vba** and **late worksheet binding vba**

Comment: Thanks Zac really appreciated I'll try tweaking the code. I think with this it's an issue with repotion with the same code without resorting variables possibly

Comment: Hi Zac, 
I took a look and removed the Hyperlink section of the code and it showed that additional lines were being added which were blank due to the    <> "Closed"  Then so I've removed this and set a static value and resolved the problem.